# How to use files from the Chrome document instead of a URL?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm a major noob so I will explain this the best I can. Anywho, I am learning steps for extension development and I wanted to fuse elements from a Greasemonkey script and a Firefox Add-on together. So far I managed to get some stuff working, but I can't seem to figure out how to make images and CSS files from the script point to the Chrome: `Skin` folder.
The current code is:

```
var newstyle = document.createElement('link');
newstyle.rel = 'stylesheet';
newstyle.href = 'http://example.com/test.css';
newstyle.type = 'text/css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newstyle);

function main(){
var assets = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
$('<div id="jumpFloatingButton" style="width:80px;height:30px;background-color:#21a0f1;background-image:url(http://colourlovers.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/patterns/2757/2757110.png);position:fixed;right:0px;bottom:0px;background-attachment: scroll;cursor: pointer;"></div>').insertAfter('body *:last');
$('<div id="jumpFloating" style="width:400px;height:500px;position:fixed;bottom:30px;right:0px;border:1px solid black;background-image:url(http://colourlovers.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/patterns/2757/2757110.png);"><ul id="jumpFloatingList" style="overflow:auto;max-height:500px;max-width:400px;margin-left:0px;"></ul></div>').insertAfter('#jumpFloatingButton');
```

The links in the above code are examples of files linked from other sources. What I would like to know is how can I make the link point from inside the Add-on's folder instead of other URLs? Like:

```
newstyle.href = 'chrome://folder/skin/overlay.css';
```

Or

```
$('<div id="jumpFloatingButton" style="width:80px;height:30px;background-color:#21a0f1;background-image:url(chrome://folder/skin/image.jpg);position:fixed;right:0px;bottom:0px;background-attachment: scroll;cursor: pointer;"></div>').insertAfter('body *:last');
```

---

I use Netbeans. My manifest

```
content file jar:chrome/file.jar!/content/
skin special classic/1.0 jar:chrome/special.jar!/skin/ contentaccessible=yes
```

I tried

```
var newstyle = document.createStyleSheet('overlay.css');
newstyle.rel = 'stylesheet';
newstyle.href = 'chrome://nb/skin/overlay.css';
newstyle.type = 'text/css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newstyle);
```

Would adding document.createStyleSheet fix it? My edit

```
$('<div id="imagestack" style="width:304px;height:64px;background-image:url("chrome://special/skin/nav.png");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark `chrome://folder/` in your `chrome.manifest` as [accessible from the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration/#contentaccessible), otherwise the web page will not be able to load it. I see that you tried to do that already but you added `contentaccessible=yes` to the `skin` entry. The documentation says:

> The contentaccessible flag applies only to content packages: it is not recognized for locale or skin registration. However, the matching locale and skin packages will also be exposed to content.

This is because you cannot mark a part of a chrome package as accessible to the web - it is either all of it (content, skin and locales) or nothing. So your `chrome.manifest` should look like this:

```
content file jar:chrome/file.jar!/content/ contentaccessible=yes
skin special classic/1.0 jar:chrome/special.jar!/skin/
```

Comment: No I am using an IDE. Also please recheck my question I have edited it with a few changes. My Chrome has been fixed up yet I'm still having this issue.

Comment: @C.Williams: The issue is not with your IDE, it is with your `chrome.manifest` file ;). Thank you for adding it to your question, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes it works! Thankyou so much Wladimir. All links can now be accessible from Chrome. (: